# How to extract json data in mysql select?

Tags: mysql, json

I have two tables, and I want to use a value from primary table (here: `person.ref`) to extract some data from a `json` field in a secondary table (here: `person_details`):

```
create table person ( 
    id int(8),
    ref varchar(20),
    primary key (id)
);

create table person_details (
    id int(8),
    details json,
    primary key (id)
);

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(details, CONCAT('$.', p.ref))
FROM person p
JOIN person_details d using (id);
```

The person_details data is like:

```
{
  "ref1": {
    ...
  }
}
```

But that does not matter, because the sql statement itself seems to be invalid:

Result:

```
#3143 - Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 12.
```

Why?

Comment: Provide sample data as INSERT INTO and desired output for it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work on MySQL >= 5.7. Check this dbfiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/esEJ9uHd

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ref` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `person_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `details` json,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `ref`) VALUES (1, 'ref1');
INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `ref`) VALUES (2, 'ref1');
INSERT INTO `person_details` (`id`, `details`) VALUES (1, '{"ref1":  {"name": "Barney"}}');
INSERT INTO `person_details` (`id`, `details`) VALUES (2, '{"ref1":  {"name": "Willma"}}');

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(details, CONCAT('$.', p.ref))
FROM person p
JOIN person_details d using (id);
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.7 there exists JSON datatype - what is the reason for LONGTEXT using? And you do not need to quote doublequote chars in the value.

Comment: I created the table in NAVICAT for testing and this is how he created the table definition DDL when I chose the field type JSON. On localhost I have 10.4.24-MariaDB. JSON is converted in longtext -> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Comment: But then you copy this to fiddle - you'd fix this. Additionally - you create fiddle using version 8.0. On version 5.7, your CHECK constraint will be cut out of the code - this version parses but ignores it.

Comment: *On localhost I have 10.4.24-MariaDB.* Yes, MariaDB have not implemented JSON datatype yet.

Comment: I didn't think it was so important and I was in a hurry. I updated the fiddle and the code pasted here with `json`.

Comment: You're correct: on empty databases the sql statement works without problems (of course without results). So it somehow has to do with the data inside, not the statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above is correct, it did not solve my issue, but I had to add doublequotes around `p.ref`, so that the concatenation results in `CONCAT($."p.ref")`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(details, CONCAT('$."', p.ref, '"'))
...
```